# Javascript Variable in Ajax Updater

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to send the javascript variable 'sortlist' to an Ajax function using the following code:

```
<div id = "output">Drag to sort</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var session = <? echo $sesh; ?>;
var track   = <? echo $trk; ?>;

var sortlist = "sortlist_" + session + "_" + track; 

Sortable.create(sortlist,{
    onUpdate:function(){
        new Ajax.Updater('output','program_sort.php',
           {onComplete:function(request){}, 
               parameters:Sortable.serialize(sortlist), 
               evalScripts:true, 
               asynchronous:true}
        )
    }
})
</script>
```

The variable appears to be passing successfully to Sortable.create (because I can sort the boxes on the webpage), but it does not appear to be passing into Sortable.serialize within Ajax.updater (because it no longer writes the sort order values to the database).

This code works when I use the literal value in Sortable.serialize, like

```
parameters:Sortable.serialize('sortlist_1_1'),
```

I have tried using sortlist as a variable with and without single and double quotes inside Sortable.serialize to no avail. What is the format required to successfully pass this variable information?

For reference, 
My AJAX/javascript experience is about a 1 (scale 1-10); my PHP/MySQL experience is about a 7 (scale 1-10).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sortable.create(sortlist,{
    onUpdate:function(sortlist){return function(){
        new Ajax.Updater('output','program_sort.php',
           {onComplete:function(request){}, 
               parameters:Sortable.serialize(sortlist), 
               evalScripts:true, 
               asynchronous:true}
        )
    };}(sortlist);
})
```

Let's go one step further then:

```
function(sortlist){
Sortable.create(sortlist,{
    onUpdate:function(){
        new Ajax.Updater('output','program_sort.php',
           {onComplete:function(request){}, 
               parameters:Sortable.serialize(sortlist), 
               evalScripts:true, 
               asynchronous:true}
        )
    }
});
}(sortlist);
```

Comment: thanks Sebastian. but it didn't work though. with the code above I am unable to sort them on the web page by drag and drop. I see where you are going with it though.

Comment: still no go. won't drag and drop on the webpage.

Comment: Which library are you using for Sortable and Ajax?

Comment: FOR SORTING: prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js
FOR SORTING: scriptaculous/1/scriptaculous.js